# Shift key pops up a menu

Tags: windows-xp, shift

A weird shift-key problem, for which all I found was sticky keys answers
First of all, I have all the sticky keys and related, Disabled.

Every windows that is currently in focus, if I press the left shift-key alone, pops up the current window menu. 
I have no idea how and why this has happened, or how to disable it. 
I could not find any reference in google about it (perhaps my search-string was not good..)

I have all the Accessibility Options turned off - sticky, filter and toggle this happens on EVERY window I am in and acts like shift+f10 (mouse right clock) I don't have the <kbd>F10</kbd> button stuck, so I don't get whats going on. on the other hand, how do I disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> shortcut?

Comment: good edit @Mark Szymanski :)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this happening in the future, click the settings button on the window referenced above. When the accessibility options screen appears, click the "Settings" button in the "Sticky Keys" portion of the window. On the next window (should be labeled "Settings For Sticky Keys"), uncheck in the box that says "Use shortcut", then click on "Apply", and close the windows. The problem should not occur once the shortcut has been disabled.

you also need to disable filter keys.

[Source1](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/help-turn-off-sticky-keys/114568.html)

[Source2](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/stickykeys.aspx)

[Google](http://www.google.com.tr/search?hl=tr&q=windows+xp+sticky+keys+disable&btnG=Ara&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: I have all the Accessibilty Options turned off - sticky, filter and toggle.