# Left shift key displays right click menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I press the left shift key, the right click menu pops up.

This is similar to the problem that I found discussed here: [Shift key pops up a menu](https://superuser.com/questions/226391/shift-key-pops-up-a-menu)

I ran a keyboard test, and it shows that whenever I press the left shift key, it registers that as shift + the menu key, which also brings up the menu (see screenshot below).

[image]

I know shift + F10 does this, and I am fairly certain the F10 key is not stuck.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem before or can only suggest some methods to solve this?

Comment: Does this issue only happen with this one keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is keyboard specific. What I don't understand is why or how a single key is registered/mapped to two keys. This also seems to happen with the LWin and LAlt keys, and pressing either ends up registering as both keys pressed.

Comment: Well, the keyboard is faulty! Or, you have some software/driver specific to the keyboard which is creating this 'shortcut' or 'autohotkey' type of thing!

Comment: Although it's most likely a hardware fault, can you check if it does the same in Safe Mode as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this issue only happens with the one keyboard, then it may be worth while just getting a new keyboard to save any headaches.

---

You can down load the free tool [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and map the Shift + Menu combination to just the left shift and see if this overwrites the fault.

Obviously this will only work if you never need to use the combination Shift+Menu

Comment: John, I think my answer is an OK answer, but, I suggest you wait a few days and don't mark it as answer to see if any one else posts!

Comment: @John, I have updated my answer with another option.

Comment: I have decided to return the keyboard. I was able to re-map some of the keys, but I'd rather just have a fully functional keyboard.